# Difference between $\ell ^{\infty}$ and $\ell^p$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

With $p \in [1,\infty)$. With the $\ell^p$, the set is to do with summations but with the $\ell ^{\infty}$ it just says the supremum of a given vector right? Can someone explain why there is no sum in this one? And what the infinity one actually means.

Comment: $\lim_{p\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[p]{\sum_i a_i^p}=\text{max}_i(a_i)$

Comment: As @Wouter said. However, note that this is for *finite* sequences. Still, it serves to motivate the definition of $\ell^\infty$ even for infinite sequences (just replace the maximum by a supremum).

Comment: You can think of an element of $\ell^p$ or $\ell^{\infty}$ as a function from the positive integers into $\mathbb{C}$ (or $\mathbb{R}$). The $\infty$ norm is the sup norm of the function $f$ given by $\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}|f(n)|$. Convergence in this norm is uniform convergence on all integers. The convergence characterizes the norm topology. The other $\ell^p$ norms are sums which can also be treated as $L^p$ norms with respect to counting measure. There is a certain sense in which $\|f\|_{\infty}=\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}\|f\|_p$, which is the reason for the $\infty$ designation.

Comment: It still just seems to me by reading these comments that the inf one is just one number. As in if $a_n=(a_1,a_2,...)$ where $a_1>a_2>...$ then when this is evaluated by the inf norm, it would be max|a_n|= a_1. Is this the case? Can someone give some better examples.

Comment: if we have $x=(1,1,1,...)$, would this exist in $\ell^{\infty}$? If yes, then why??